# fix position covering the content but relative postion doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making the fixed navigation header. The whole web page doing fine when i set the relative postion and it also doesn't cover the content of the page its all good.

However, when i set the postion to fixed, the header navigation bar cover the content.

How can i make the sticky navigation header without covering the web page content.

I would really appreciate if anyone could point out my mistake.

```js
const select = document.querySelectorAll(".selectBtn");
const option = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
let index = 1;

select.forEach((a) => {
  a.addEventListener("click", (b) => {
    const next = b.target.nextElementSibling;
    next.classList.toggle("toggle");
    next.style.zIndex = index++;
  });
});
option.forEach((a) => {
  a.addEventListener("click", (b) => {
    b.target.parentElement.classList.remove("toggle");

    const parent = b.target.closest(".select").children[0];
    parent.setAttribute("data-type", b.target.getAttribute("data-type"));
    parent.innerText = b.target.innerText;
  });
});
```

```css
footer {
  background: deeppink;
  line-height: 3;
}

.left-sidebar {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.right-sidebar {
  background: forestgreen;
}

.main-container,
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .content {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  main {
    flex: 2;
    order: 2;
    min-height: 80vh;
  }
  .left-sidebar {
    order: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .right-sidebar {
    flex: 1;
    order: 3;
  }
}

.person {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.well {
  background: transparent;
  border-style: none;
}

.item {
  width: 250px !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin: 19px;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 15px #CCC;
}

.col-md-3:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 25px #ccc;
}

.thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.p-title {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 16px;
}

.lead {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.img-id {
  object-fit: cover !important;
  object-position: center;
  height: 250px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

#item-link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container4header {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 10px 30px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-button {
  font-family: "Arial";
  text-transform: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #08ac4b;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.searchitems {
  font-family: "Arial";
  outline: 0;
  color: #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.searchitems:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #08ac4b;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #08ac4b;
}

#citySearch {
  font-family: "Arial";
  outline: 0;
  color: #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#citySearch:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #08ac4b;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #08ac4b;
}

.button2 {
  font-family: "Arial";
  text-transform: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #252525;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.select {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Arial";
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}

.select .selectBtn {
  background: var(--bg1);
  padding: 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: #fff;
}

.select .selectBtn:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 15px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.select .selectBtn.toggle {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.select .selectBtn.toggle:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
}

.select .selectDropdown {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Arial";
  max-height: 240px;
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: var(--bg1);
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
  transform-origin: top center;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.select .selectDropdown .option {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select .selectDropdown .option:hover {
  background: #edf7f1;
}

.select .selectDropdown.toggle {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <header>
    <div class="container4header">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/logo/mdb-transparent.png" height="30" alt=""></a>
        <div class="center-group">
          <div class="select">
            <div class="selectBtn" data-type="firstOption">
              Choose a category
            </div>
            <div class="selectDropdown">
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">Choose a category</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <input id="citySearch" type="text" placeholder="City">
          <input type="text" class="searchitems" placeholder="Search for an item">
          <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div class="right-group">
          <button type="submit" class="button2">Sign Up</button>
          <button type="submit" class="button2">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <main>

      <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="well well-sm">
          <div id="view" class="btn-group">
          </div>

          <div id="products" class="row list-group">

            <!-- Single product -->
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/using/convert-color-image-black-white/jcr_content/main-pars/before_and_after/image-before/Landscape-Color.jpg" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end Single product -->

            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Mona_Lisa-restored.jpg/1200px-Mona_Lisa-restored.jpg" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541963463532-d68292c34b19?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520528305/table_n1bjhv.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520528305/house2_gs4cr6.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520528305/greysofa_ys6lwl.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520528305/furniture_sddzpz.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520529781/sofa_xlb0hz.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520529781/pink_fby5uh.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520529781/couch_o9wlyx.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520529781/greysofa_pjqko4.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520532750/blue_dfokic.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520532750/orange_hlsunx.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520532750/weird_yp8qxn.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520528305/furniture_sddzpz.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520528305/greysofa_ys6lwl.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->

    </main>





    <aside class="left-sidebar">LEFT SIDEBAR</aside>
    <aside class="right-sidebar">RIGHT SIDEBAR</aside>
    </div>
    <footer>FOOTER</footer>
  </div>
```

I want to be like this in this picture i used relative position but i want to make fixed position.

[image]

Comment: Add a  margin-top to content that matches the height of your header

Comment: One of the options is to set `position: sticky` to `header` instead of `position: fixed` for `container4header`

Comment: @IvanBeliakov still the same sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
footer {
    background: deeppink;
    line-height: 3;
  }
  
  .left-sidebar {
    background: dodgerblue;
  }
  
  .right-sidebar {
    background: forestgreen;
  }
  
  .main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 5em;
  }
  
  @media all and (min-width: 768px) {
    .content {
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    main {
      flex: 2;
      order: 2;
      min-height: 80vh;
    }
    .left-sidebar {
      order: 1;
      flex: 1;
    }
    .right-sidebar {
      flex: 1;
      order: 3;
    }
  }
  
  .person {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
  }
  
  .well {
    background: transparent;
    border-style: none;
  }
  
  .item {
    width: 250px !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin: 19px;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 15px #CCC;
  }
  
  .col-md-3:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 25px #ccc;
  }
  
  .thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  
  .p-title {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  .lead {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  
  .img-id {
    object-fit: cover !important;
    object-position: center;
    height: 250px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  
  #item-link {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .container4header {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  
  .wrapper {
    padding: 10px 30px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .search-button {
    font-family: "Arial";
    text-transform: none;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #08ac4b;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
    transition: all 0.3 ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
  }
  
  .searchitems {
    font-family: "Arial";
    outline: 0;
    color: #000000;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 350px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .searchitems:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #08ac4b;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #08ac4b;
  }
  
  #citySearch {
    font-family: "Arial";
    outline: 0;
    color: #000000;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  #citySearch:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #08ac4b;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #08ac4b;
  }
  
  .button2 {
    font-family: "Arial";
    text-transform: none;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #252525;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
    transition: all 0.3 ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
  }
  
  .logo {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
  }
  
  .select {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Arial";
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    color: #000000;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
  }
  
  .select .selectBtn {
    background: var(--bg1);
    padding: 10px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  .select .selectBtn:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    right: 15px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: 0.2s ease;
  }
  
  .select .selectBtn.toggle {
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .select .selectBtn.toggle:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
  }
  
  .select .selectDropdown {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Arial";
    max-height: 240px;
    color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: var(--bg1);
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
    transform: scale(1, 0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  
  .select .selectDropdown .option {
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .select .selectDropdown .option:hover {
    background: #edf7f1;
  }
  
  .select .selectDropdown.toggle {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoWb4.png)

Is this how you want the webpage to look? Just add margin to the top of your content div.

Comment: Yes i want to do it like that

Comment: Copy the CSS code above from the comment I just edited. You need to separate the .main-container,content{ display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;} to .main-container{display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;} and .content{display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; margin-top:5em;} in your CSS and then you page will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you wrote that `position: sticky` doesn't work. I don't know why. Take a look at this snippet. As you can see, header with `position: sticky` doesn't overflow the main content but is still fixed to top. I added these styles:

```
header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

I deleted these styles:

```
.container4header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```js
const select = document.querySelectorAll(".selectBtn");
const option = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
let index = 1;

select.forEach((a) => {
  a.addEventListener("click", (b) => {
    const next = b.target.nextElementSibling;
    next.classList.toggle("toggle");
    next.style.zIndex = index++;
  });
});
option.forEach((a) => {
  a.addEventListener("click", (b) => {
    b.target.parentElement.classList.remove("toggle");

    const parent = b.target.closest(".select").children[0];
    parent.setAttribute("data-type", b.target.getAttribute("data-type"));
    parent.innerText = b.target.innerText;
  });
});
```

```css
footer {
  background: deeppink;
  line-height: 3;
}

.left-sidebar {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.right-sidebar {
  background: forestgreen;
}

.main-container,
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .content {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  main {
    flex: 2;
    order: 2;
    min-height: 80vh;
  }
  .left-sidebar {
    order: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .right-sidebar {
    flex: 1;
    order: 3;
  }
}

.person {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.well {
  background: transparent;
  border-style: none;
}

.item {
  width: 250px !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin: 19px;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 15px #CCC;
}

.col-md-3:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 25px #ccc;
}

.thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.p-title {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 16px;
}

.lead {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.img-id {
  object-fit: cover !important;
  object-position: center;
  height: 250px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

#item-link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.container4header {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  z-index: 100;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 10px 30px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-button {
  font-family: "Arial";
  text-transform: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #08ac4b;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.searchitems {
  font-family: "Arial";
  outline: 0;
  color: #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.searchitems:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #08ac4b;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #08ac4b;
}

#citySearch {
  font-family: "Arial";
  outline: 0;
  color: #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#citySearch:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #08ac4b;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #08ac4b;
}

.button2 {
  font-family: "Arial";
  text-transform: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #252525;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.select {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Arial";
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}

.select .selectBtn {
  background: var(--bg1);
  padding: 10px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: #fff;
}

.select .selectBtn:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 15px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.select .selectBtn.toggle {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.select .selectBtn.toggle:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
}

.select .selectDropdown {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Arial";
  max-height: 240px;
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: var(--bg1);
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
  transform-origin: top center;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.select .selectDropdown .option {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select .selectDropdown .option:hover {
  background: #edf7f1;
}

.select .selectDropdown.toggle {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <header>
    <div class="container4header">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/logo/mdb-transparent.png" height="30" alt=""></a>
        <div class="center-group">
          <div class="select">
            <div class="selectBtn" data-type="firstOption">
              Choose a category
            </div>
            <div class="selectDropdown">
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">Choose a category</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>
              <div class="option" data-type="firstOption">All categories</div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <input id="citySearch" type="text" placeholder="City">
          <input type="text" class="searchitems" placeholder="Search for an item">
          <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div class="right-group">
          <button type="submit" class="button2">Sign Up</button>
          <button type="submit" class="button2">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <main>

      <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="well well-sm">
          <div id="view" class="btn-group">
          </div>

          <div id="products" class="row list-group">

            <!-- Single product -->
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/using/convert-color-image-black-white/jcr_content/main-pars/before_and_after/image-before/Landscape-Color.jpg" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end Single product -->

            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Mona_Lisa-restored.jpg/1200px-Mona_Lisa-restored.jpg" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541963463532-d68292c34b19?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520528305/table_n1bjhv.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520528305/house2_gs4cr6.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520528305/greysofa_ys6lwl.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520528305/furniture_sddzpz.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520529781/sofa_xlb0hz.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520529781/pink_fby5uh.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520529781/couch_o9wlyx.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520529781/greysofa_pjqko4.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520532750/blue_dfokic.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520532750/orange_hlsunx.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520532750/weird_yp8qxn.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520528305/furniture_sddzpz.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="item-link" class="item col-xs-4 col-md-3" onclick="window.location='https://www.youtube.com'">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-id" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnhwxgf8i/image/upload/c_scale,h_250,w_400/v1520528305/greysofa_ys6lwl.png" alt="" />
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                  <div class="person">
                    <p class="person-name">Person Name</p>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                  <p class="p-title">
                    Old used box</p>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                      <p class="lead">
                        Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->

    </main>





    <aside class="left-sidebar">LEFT SIDEBAR</aside>
    <aside class="right-sidebar">RIGHT SIDEBAR</aside>
    </div>
    <footer>FOOTER</footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: sorry i only added the position: sticky but didn't added the top: 0; @IvanBelikova

Comment: Oh, I see. Then everything is OK :)

Answer (score 0):

An Element with a `fixed` position will have the size of the browser **viewport**.
Therefore, a `fixed` element with `height: 100%; width: 100%` is always going to cover the whole browser window, unless there's a parent-element up the DOM with `transform: translate`, in which case the new "viewport" area will be of this parent element, and not of the window viewport.

The same element with a `relative` position will only have the size of its parent element when it's fully stretched.

If you want to display a fixed header with a correct height, you can use this for example:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 3rem;
    z-index: 2;
{
```